# Error: The CXX compiler identification is unknown | clang & clang++ path not found

Tags: android, cmake, clang, trustwallet

I'm trying to setup and build https://github.com/trustwallet/wallet-core using Android Studio on Ubuntu. I followed the step-by-step prerequisites guide for [building the project](https://developer.trustwallet.com/developer/wallet-core/developing-the-library/building). When I executed the ./bootstrap.sh for getting the full build, it threw the error:

```
-- The CXX compiler identification is unknown
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:9 (project):
  The CMAKE_C_COMPILER:

    /usr/bin/clang

  is not a full path to an existing compiler tool.

  Tell CMake where to find the compiler by setting either the environment
  variable "CC" or the CMake cache entry CMAKE_C_COMPILER to the full path to
  the compiler, or to the compiler name if it is in the PATH.


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:9 (project):
  The CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:

    clang++

  is not a full path and was not found in the PATH.

  Tell CMake where to find the compiler by setting either the environment
  variable "CXX" or the CMake cache entry CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER to the full path
  to the compiler, or to the compiler name if it is in the PATH.
```

The complete error log is:

```
Compiling the C compiler identification source file "CMakeCCompilerId.c" failed.
Compiler: clang 
Build flags: 
Id flags:  

The output was:
No such file or directory


Compiling the C compiler identification source file "CMakeCCompilerId.c" failed.
Compiler: clang 
Build flags: 
Id flags: -c 

The output was:
No such file or directory


Compiling the C compiler identification source file "CMakeCCompilerId.c" failed.
Compiler: clang 
Build flags: 
Id flags: -Aa 

The output was:
No such file or directory


Compiling the C compiler identification source file "CMakeCCompilerId.c" failed.
Compiler: clang 
Build flags: 
Id flags: -D__CLASSIC_C__ 

The output was:
No such file or directory


Compiling the C compiler identification source file "CMakeCCompilerId.c" failed.
Compiler: clang 
Build flags: 
Id flags: --target=arm-arm-none-eabi;-mcpu=cortex-m3 

The output was:
No such file or directory


Compiling the C compiler identification source file "CMakeCCompilerId.c" failed.
Compiler: clang 
Build flags: 
Id flags: -c;-I__does_not_exist__ 

The output was:
No such file or directory


Compiling the C compiler identification source file "CMakeCCompilerId.c" failed.
Compiler: clang 
Build flags: 
Id flags:  

The output was:
No such file or directory


Compiling the C compiler identification source file "CMakeCCompilerId.c" failed.
Compiler: clang 
Build flags: 
Id flags: -c 

The output was:
No such file or directory


Compiling the C compiler identification source file "CMakeCCompilerId.c" failed.
Compiler: clang 
Build flags: 
Id flags: -Aa 

The output was:
No such file or directory


Compiling the C compiler identification source file "CMakeCCompilerId.c" failed.
Compiler: clang 
Build flags: 
Id flags: -D__CLASSIC_C__ 

The output was:
No such file or directory


Compiling the C compiler identification source file "CMakeCCompilerId.c" failed.
Compiler: clang 
Build flags: 
Id flags: --target=arm-arm-none-eabi;-mcpu=cortex-m3 

The output was:
No such file or directory


Compiling the C compiler identification source file "CMakeCCompilerId.c" failed.
Compiler: clang 
Build flags: 
Id flags: -c;-I__does_not_exist__ 

The output was:
No such file or directory


Checking whether the C compiler is IAR using "" did not match "IAR .+ Compiler":
Checking whether the C compiler is IAR using "" did not match "IAR .+ Compiler":
Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler: clang++ 
Build flags: 
Id flags:  

The output was:
No such file or directory


Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler: clang++ 
Build flags: 
Id flags: -c 

The output was:
No such file or directory


Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler: clang++ 
Build flags: 
Id flags: --c++ 

The output was:
No such file or directory


Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler: clang++ 
Build flags: 
Id flags: --ec++ 

The output was:
No such file or directory


Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler: clang++ 
Build flags: 
Id flags: --target=arm-arm-none-eabi;-mcpu=cortex-m3 

The output was:
No such file or directory


Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler: clang++ 
Build flags: 
Id flags: -c;-I__does_not_exist__ 

The output was:
No such file or directory


Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler: clang++ 
Build flags: 
Id flags:  

The output was:
No such file or directory


Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler: clang++ 
Build flags: 
Id flags: -c 

The output was:
No such file or directory


Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler: clang++ 
Build flags: 
Id flags: --c++ 

The output was:
No such file or directory


Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler: clang++ 
Build flags: 
Id flags: --ec++ 

The output was:
No such file or directory


Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler: clang++ 
Build flags: 
Id flags: --target=arm-arm-none-eabi;-mcpu=cortex-m3 

The output was:
No such file or directory


Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler: clang++ 
Build flags: 
Id flags: -c;-I__does_not_exist__ 

The output was:
No such file or directory


Checking whether the CXX compiler is IAR using "" did not match "IAR .+ Compiler":
Checking whether the CXX compiler is IAR using "" did not match "IAR .+ Compiler":
Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler: /usr/bin/clang++ 
Build flags: 
Id flags:  

The output was:
1
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lstdc++: No such file or directory
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)


Detecting CXX compiler ABI info failed to compile with the following output:
Change Dir: /home/vishal/AndroidStudioProjects/wallet-core/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command(s):/usr/bin/gmake -f Makefile cmTC_6bc86/fast && /usr/bin/gmake  -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_6bc86.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_6bc86.dir/build
gmake[1]: Entering directory '/home/vishal/AndroidStudioProjects/wallet-core/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
Building CXX object CMakeFiles/cmTC_6bc86.dir/CMakeCXXCompilerABI.cpp.o
/usr/bin/clang++   -v -MD -MT CMakeFiles/cmTC_6bc86.dir/CMakeCXXCompilerABI.cpp.o -MF CMakeFiles/cmTC_6bc86.dir/CMakeCXXCompilerABI.cpp.o.d -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_6bc86.dir/CMakeCXXCompilerABI.cpp.o -c /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/CMakeCXXCompilerABI.cpp
Ubuntu clang version 14.0.0-1ubuntu1.1
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/bin
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/12
Selected GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/12
Candidate multilib: .;@m64
Selected multilib: .;@m64
 (in-process)
 "/usr/lib/llvm-14/bin/clang" -cc1 -triple x86_64-pc-linux-gnu -emit-obj -mrelax-all --mrelax-relocations -disable-free -clear-ast-before-backend -disable-llvm-verifier -discard-value-names -main-file-name CMakeCXXCompilerABI.cpp -mrelocation-model pic -pic-level 2 -pic-is-pie -mframe-pointer=all -fmath-errno -ffp-contract=on -fno-rounding-math -mconstructor-aliases -funwind-tables=2 -target-cpu x86-64 -tune-cpu generic -mllvm -treat-scalable-fixed-error-as-warning -debugger-tuning=gdb -v -fcoverage-compilation-dir=/home/vishal/AndroidStudioProjects/wallet-core/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp -resource-dir /usr/lib/llvm-14/lib/clang/14.0.0 -dependency-file CMakeFiles/cmTC_6bc86.dir/CMakeCXXCompilerABI.cpp.o.d -MT CMakeFiles/cmTC_6bc86.dir/CMakeCXXCompilerABI.cpp.o -sys-header-deps -internal-isystem /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/12/../../../../include/c++ -internal-isystem /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/12/../../../../include/c++/x86_64-linux-gnu -internal-isystem /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/12/../../../../include/c++/backward -internal-isystem /usr/lib/llvm-14/lib/clang/14.0.0/include -internal-isystem /usr/local/include -internal-isystem /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/12/../../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/include -internal-externc-isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu -internal-externc-isystem /include -internal-externc-isystem /usr/include -fdeprecated-macro -fdebug-compilation-dir=/home/vishal/AndroidStudioProjects/wallet-core/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp -ferror-limit 19 -fgnuc-version=4.2.1 -fcxx-exceptions -fexceptions -faddrsig -D__GCC_HAVE_DWARF2_CFI_ASM=1 -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_6bc86.dir/CMakeCXXCompilerABI.cpp.o -x c++ /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/CMakeCXXCompilerABI.cpp
clang -cc1 version 14.0.0 based upon LLVM 14.0.0 default target x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/12/../../../../include/c++/x86_64-linux-gnu"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/12/../../../../include/c++/backward"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/12/../../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/12/../../../../include/c++
 /usr/lib/llvm-14/lib/clang/14.0.0/include
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu
 /usr/include
End of search list.
Linking CXX executable cmTC_6bc86
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/cmTC_6bc86.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/clang++  -v CMakeFiles/cmTC_6bc86.dir/CMakeCXXCompilerABI.cpp.o -o cmTC_6bc86 
Ubuntu clang version 14.0.0-1ubuntu1.1
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/bin
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/12
Selected GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/12
Candidate multilib: .;@m64
Selected multilib: .;@m64
 "/usr/bin/ld" -pie -z relro --hash-style=gnu --build-id --eh-frame-hdr -m elf_x86_64 -dynamic-linker /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 -o cmTC_6bc86 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/12/crtbeginS.o -L/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/12 -L/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/12/../../../../lib64 -L/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/lib/../lib64 -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/../lib64 -L/usr/lib/llvm-14/bin/../lib -L/lib -L/usr/lib CMakeFiles/cmTC_6bc86.dir/CMakeCXXCompilerABI.cpp.o -lstdc++ -lm -lgcc_s -lgcc -lc -lgcc_s -lgcc /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/12/crtendS.o /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crtn.o
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lstdc++: No such file or directory
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
gmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cmTC_6bc86.dir/build.make:100: cmTC_6bc86] Error 1
gmake[1]: Leaving directory '/home/vishal/AndroidStudioProjects/wallet-core/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
gmake: *** [Makefile:127: cmTC_6bc86/fast] Error 2




Determining if the CXX compiler works failed with the following output:
Change Dir: /home/vishal/AndroidStudioProjects/wallet-core/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command(s):/usr/bin/gmake -f Makefile cmTC_12a09/fast && /usr/bin/gmake  -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_12a09.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_12a09.dir/build
gmake[1]: Entering directory '/home/vishal/AndroidStudioProjects/wallet-core/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
Building CXX object CMakeFiles/cmTC_12a09.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o
/usr/bin/clang++    -MD -MT CMakeFiles/cmTC_12a09.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o -MF CMakeFiles/cmTC_12a09.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o.d -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_12a09.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o -c /home/vishal/AndroidStudioProjects/wallet-core/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/testCXXCompiler.cxx
Linking CXX executable cmTC_12a09
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/cmTC_12a09.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/clang++ CMakeFiles/cmTC_12a09.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o -o cmTC_12a09 
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lstdc++: No such file or directory
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
gmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cmTC_12a09.dir/build.make:100: cmTC_12a09] Error 1
gmake[1]: Leaving directory '/home/vishal/AndroidStudioProjects/wallet-core/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
gmake: *** [Makefile:127: cmTC_12a09/fast] Error 2



Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler: clang++ 
Build flags: 
Id flags:  

The output was:
No such file or directory


Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler: clang++ 
Build flags: 
Id flags: -c 

The output was:
No such file or directory


Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler: clang++ 
Build flags: 
Id flags: --c++ 

The output was:
No such file or directory


Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler: clang++ 
Build flags: 
Id flags: --ec++ 

The output was:
No such file or directory


Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler: clang++ 
Build flags: 
Id flags: --target=arm-arm-none-eabi;-mcpu=cortex-m3 

The output was:
No such file or directory


Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler: clang++ 
Build flags: 
Id flags: -c;-I__does_not_exist__ 

The output was:
No such file or directory


Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler: clang++ 
Build flags: 
Id flags:  

The output was:
No such file or directory


Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler: clang++ 
Build flags: 
Id flags: -c 

The output was:
No such file or directory


Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler: clang++ 
Build flags: 
Id flags: --c++ 

The output was:
No such file or directory


Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler: clang++ 
Build flags: 
Id flags: --ec++ 

The output was:
No such file or directory


Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler: clang++ 
Build flags: 
Id flags: --target=arm-arm-none-eabi;-mcpu=cortex-m3 

The output was:
No such file or directory


Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler: clang++ 
Build flags: 
Id flags: -c;-I__does_not_exist__ 

The output was:
No such file or directory


Checking whether the CXX compiler is IAR using "" did not match "IAR .+ Compiler":
Checking whether the CXX compiler is IAR using "" did not match "IAR .+ Compiler":
```

The CMakeLists.txt file:

```
# Copyright © 2017-2022 Trust Wallet.
#
# This file is part of Trust. The full Trust copyright notice, including
# terms governing use, modification, and redistribution, is contained in the
# file LICENSE at the root of the source code distribution tree.

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.18 FATAL_ERROR)

project(TrustWalletCore)

if (NOT ("${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID}" MATCHES "Clang"))
    message(FATAL_ERROR "You should use clang compiler")
endif ()

if ("$ENV{PREFIX}" STREQUAL "")
    set(PREFIX "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/build/local")
else ()
    set(PREFIX "$ENV{PREFIX}")
endif ()

include(GNUInstallDirs)
include(cmake/StandardSettings.cmake)
include(cmake/CompilerWarnings.cmake)
include(cmake/StaticAnalyzers.cmake)
include(cmake/FindHostPackage.cmake)

set(WALLET_CORE_RS_TARGET_DIR ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/rust/target)
add_library(${PROJECT_NAME}_INTERFACE INTERFACE)
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME}_INTERFACE INTERFACE ${PREFIX}/include)
target_link_directories(${PROJECT_NAME}_INTERFACE INTERFACE ${PREFIX}/lib)
target_link_directories(${PROJECT_NAME}_INTERFACE INTERFACE ${WALLET_CORE_RS_TARGET_DIR}/release)
set_project_warnings(${PROJECT_NAME}_INTERFACE)

add_subdirectory(trezor-crypto)
set(WALLET_CORE_RS_LIB libwallet_core_rs.a)

set(WALLET_CORE_BINDGEN ${WALLET_CORE_RS_TARGET_DIR}/release/${WALLET_CORE_RS_LIB})
if (TW_COMPILE_WASM)
    message(STATUS "Wasm build enabled")
    set(WALLET_CORE_BINDGEN ${WALLET_CORE_RS_TARGET_DIR}/wasm32-unknown-emscripten/release/${WALLET_CORE_RS_LIB})
    add_subdirectory(wasm)
endif ()

find_host_package(Boost REQUIRED)

include(ExternalProject)

# Dependencies
include(cmake/Protobuf.cmake)

# Source files
if (${ANDROID})
    message("Configuring for Android JNI")
    file(GLOB_RECURSE core_sources src/*.c src/*.cc src/*.cpp src/*.h jni/cpp/*.cpp jni/cpp/*.h)
    if (${KOTLIN})
        file(GLOB_RECURSE specific_sources
                jni/kotlin/*.h
                jni/kotlin/*.c
                kotlin/wallet-core-kotlin/src/commonAndroidJvmMain/cpp/generated/*.h
                kotlin/wallet-core-kotlin/src/commonAndroidJvmMain/cpp/generated/*.c
                )
    else ()
        file(GLOB_RECURSE specific_sources jni/android/*.h jni/android/*.c)
    endif ()
    set(sources ${core_sources} ${specific_sources})
    add_library(TrustWalletCore SHARED ${sources} ${PROTO_SRCS} ${PROTO_HDRS})
    find_library(log-lib log)
    if (${CMAKE_ANDROID_ARCH_ABI} STREQUAL "arm64-v8a")
        set(WALLET_CORE_BINDGEN ${WALLET_CORE_RS_TARGET_DIR}/aarch64-linux-android/release/${WALLET_CORE_RS_LIB})
    elseif (${CMAKE_ANDROID_ARCH_ABI} STREQUAL "x86")
        set(WALLET_CORE_BINDGEN ${WALLET_CORE_RS_TARGET_DIR}/i686-linux-android/release/${WALLET_CORE_RS_LIB})
    elseif (${CMAKE_ANDROID_ARCH_ABI} STREQUAL "armeabi-v7a")
        set(WALLET_CORE_BINDGEN ${WALLET_CORE_RS_TARGET_DIR}/armv7-linux-androideabi/release/${WALLET_CORE_RS_LIB})
    elseif (${CMAKE_ANDROID_ARCH_ABI} STREQUAL "x86_64")
        set(WALLET_CORE_BINDGEN ${WALLET_CORE_RS_TARGET_DIR}/x86_64-linux-android/release/${WALLET_CORE_RS_LIB})
    endif ()
    target_link_libraries(TrustWalletCore PUBLIC ${WALLET_CORE_BINDGEN} ${PROJECT_NAME}_INTERFACE PRIVATE TrezorCrypto protobuf ${log-lib} Boost::boost)
elseif (${TW_COMPILE_JAVA})
    message("Configuring for JNI")
    file(GLOB_RECURSE core_sources src/*.c src/*.cc src/*.cpp src/*.h jni/cpp/*.cpp jni/cpp/*.h)
    if (${TW_COMPILE_KOTLIN})
        file(GLOB_RECURSE specific_sources
                jni/kotlin/*.h
                jni/kotlin/*.c
                kotlin/wallet-core-kotlin/src/commonAndroidJvmMain/cpp/generated/*.h
                kotlin/wallet-core-kotlin/src/commonAndroidJvmMain/cpp/generated/*.c
                )
    else ()
        file(GLOB_RECURSE specific_sources jni/android/*.h jni/android/*.c)
    endif ()
    set(sources ${core_sources} ${specific_sources})
    add_library(TrustWalletCore SHARED ${sources} ${PROTO_SRCS} ${PROTO_HDRS})
    find_package(JNI REQUIRED)
    target_include_directories(TrustWalletCore PRIVATE ${JNI_INCLUDE_DIRS})
    target_link_libraries(TrustWalletCore PUBLIC ${WALLET_CORE_BINDGEN} ${PROJECT_NAME}_INTERFACE PRIVATE TrezorCrypto protobuf Boost::boost)
else ()
    message("Configuring standalone")
    file(GLOB_RECURSE sources src/*.c src/*.cc src/*.cpp src/*.h)
    add_library(TrustWalletCore STATIC ${sources} ${PROTO_SRCS} ${PROTO_HDRS})
    target_link_libraries(TrustWalletCore PUBLIC ${WALLET_CORE_BINDGEN} ${PROJECT_NAME}_INTERFACE PRIVATE TrezorCrypto protobuf Boost::boost)
endif ()

if (TW_CODE_COVERAGE AND CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID MATCHES "GNU|Clang")
    target_enable_coverage(TrustWalletCore)
endif ()

if (TW_CLANG_ASAN)
    target_enable_asan(TrustWalletCore)
endif ()

# Define headers for this library. PUBLIC headers are used for compiling the
# library, and will be added to consumers' build paths.
target_include_directories(TrustWalletCore
        PUBLIC
        $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include>
        $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:include>
        PRIVATE
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/jni/cpp
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/build/local/include
        )

if (TW_UNIT_TESTS)
    add_subdirectory(tests)
endif ()

if (TW_BUILD_EXAMPLES)
    add_subdirectory(walletconsole/lib)
    add_subdirectory(walletconsole)
endif ()

if (TW_ENABLE_PVS_STUDIO)
    tw_add_pvs_studio_target(TrustWalletCore)
endif ()

if (TW_ENABLE_CLANG_TIDY)
    tw_add_clang_tidy_target(TrustWalletCore)
endif ()

if (TW_UNITY_BUILD)
    set_target_properties(TrustWalletCore PROPERTIES UNITY_BUILD ON)

    file(GLOB_RECURSE PROTOBUF_SOURCE_FILES CONFIGURE_DEPENDS src/Cosmos/Protobuf/*.pb.cc src/Hedera/Protobuf/*.pb.cc src/proto/*.pb.cc)
    foreach (file ${PROTOBUF_SOURCE_FILES})
        set_property(SOURCE ${file} PROPERTY SKIP_UNITY_BUILD_INCLUSION ON)
    endforeach ()
    message(STATUS "Unity build activated")
endif ()

configure_file(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/swift/cpp.xcconfig.in ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/swift/cpp.xcconfig @ONLY)

install(TARGETS TrustWalletCore
        LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}
        ARCHIVE DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}
        )

install(
        DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/
        DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR}/WalletCore
        FILES_MATCHING PATTERN "*.h"
)

install(DIRECTORY include/ DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR})
```

I'm not having much idea about clang and cmake stuff, would appreciate for your time and help provided!

Answer (score 0):

Try installing clang first:

```
sudo apt install clang
```

If the issue still persists, try creating a symlink:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/clang-${VERSION} /usr/bin/clang
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/clang++-${VERSION} /usr/bin/clang++
```

You can manually find VERSION by executing:

```
ls -la /usr/bin | grep clang
```